# SQL Query Help SUM of Columns accross multiple tables

Tags: sql, sum

Hi I wonder if you can help with the following query , I am going around in circles trying to get the syntax correct.

I have two Tables Orders

```
OrderID | Product ID | LineTotal
   1         ABC          2
   2         CDE          3
   2         DEF          1
```

and Products Table Containing the Weight and Cost

```
ProductID | Weight | Cost 
   ABC        1        1
   CDE        2        2  
   DEF        1        0.5
```

So for each order ID I need to SUM the LineTotal the Weight and the Cost.

Thanks for some pointers on how to go about this as I am getting errors with joins and silly results

Thanks

Comment: with your demo data, What is the result you're expecting exactly ?

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Using MySql , but also exported all to Access to try it in there also

Answer (score 1):

It should be very simple if I got the task right:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.ProductID, sum = (o.LineTotal + p.Weight + p.Cost) 
FROM ORDERS o
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS p on o.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: Anything that adds weight (kilos?) to cost (dollars?) looks wrong. Two kilos plus two dollars  equals four of what?.. The fact that you can add the two numbers mathematically changes nothing.

Comment: OK I think I didn't explain correct :- So For OrderID 2 I would Expect Linetotal = 4 , Weight = 3 , Cost = 2.5  Does that clear it up ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select t3.OrderID , SUM(t3.SUM1) As TotalSum  
From (Select t1.*,t2.Weight,t2.Cost,t1.LineTotal+t2.Weight+t2.Cost AS Sum1 
      from Orders t1 
      INNER JOIN Products t2 
      ON t1.ProductID=t2.ProductID ) t3 
Group BY t3.OrderID
```